# am I allowed to move .git folder and .gitignore file into the actual project directory?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am not so into GIT and I have the following doubt: I created an empty repository on BitBucket then I cloned it on my filesystem of my Linux Ubuntu machine. So a directory with the same name of my BitBucket repository was created on my file system. This directory contains the **.git** hiddend folder and the **.gitignore** hidden file that handle my repository

Then I accessed to this directory via shell and I created an Angular project by:

```
sudo ng new gestionale-medico-portal --style=scss
```

that creates the **gestionale-medico-portal** subfolder representing my actual project that I have to put into the GIT repository.

My question is: can I simply move my **.git** folder and my **.gitignore** file into this subfolder or it can create problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can move those folders. Git determines if it's a git project or not based on if there is a .git folder on this level or higher levels.